# Error about Subscript indices of sum function for float matrix matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix `202x141x3` that called `M` matrix. I want to perform the code

```
sum(M,3);
```

However, I got error such as

```
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

I debugged and saw the content in M matrix, it has not problem. But I cannot use the above function. Could you see my M.mat matrix at [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/081zhqntgg48vcl/M.mat?dl=0) and let me know how can I use above function for my M.mat matrix

Comment: Are you sure you didn't instaciate a variable called `sum`?

Comment: What does it mean of instaciate ?

Comment: What is data type of the `M` matrix ?

Comment: I mean, did you create a variable named `sum`? Try `clear sum` then retry

Comment: Right. I saw it.I found the error. It is sum variable

Comment: Ok, gonna post an answer about it for the future people getting this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did set a variable under the name `sum`

```
a = [1 2 3 ; 4 -5 6; 7 8 9]
sum = 1;


>> sum(a)
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.


clear sum;
>> sum(a)

ans =

    12    5    18
```